# How to add multiple numeric values in a single cell of a large list in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I want to calculate the sum of product quantity against a shipment_id. I have dataframe with two columns.

```
    shipment_id    details
    XYQWE13        [{"orderid"=1,"quantity"=>2},{"orderid"=2,"quantity"=>1}]
    UYTDW54        [{"orderid"=1,"quantity"=>5},{"orderid"=2,"quantity"=>5}]
    SKFEF32        [{"orderid"=1,"quantity"=>2},{"orderid"=2,"quantity"=>1},{"orderid"=3,"quantity"=>5}]
```

So I will have to fetch the numeric value only after the quantity part. I tried this to extract quantity and the number against it

```
    y <- stringr::str_extract_all(string = raw_data_shipment2$details, pattern = '"quantity"=>[0-99]+')
```

Which gave me a large list

```
     Name           Type                   Value 
     y              list(3)                List of length 3
     [[1]]          character [1]          '"quantity"=>2''"quantity"=>1'
     [[2]]          character [1]          '"quantity"=>5''"quantity"=>5'
     [[2]]          character [1]          '"quantity"=>2''"quantity"=>1''"quantity"=>5'
```

Further using this

```
     y2 <- stringr::str_extract_all(string = y, pattern = '=>[0-99]+')
     y3 <- stringr::str_extract_all(string = y2, pattern = '[0-99]+')
```

Gave me this result of this large list

```
     Name           Type                   Value 
     y3             list(3)                List of length 3
     [[1]]          character [1]          '2''1'
     [[2]]          character [1]          '5''5'
     [[2]]          character [1]          '2''1''5'
```

Now I wanted to sum the numeric part and was hoping I could cbind it with my original dataframe. But I'm stuck on how to sum it.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to loop through the list.  `sapply(y2, function(x) unlist(str_extract_all(x, '=>[0-99]+')))`

Comment: @akrun Hi, what is the x in function here ?

Comment: It is anonymous function call (`lambda` in `python`)

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, it gave the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `stringr` I am going to assume you are using other `tidyverse` packages--specifically `purrr`.  If you are you should be able to use the map function to sum y1, y2, y3, etc:

```
z1 <- purrr::map(y1, ~sum(as.numeric(.)))
z2 <- purrr::map(y2, ~sum(as.numeric(.)))
z3 <- purrr::map(y3, ~sum(as.numeric(.)))
```

Then you could bind z1,z2,z3, etc.

Comment: I'm glad!  You could probably do this at a higher level if you wanted (e.g. `purrr::map(raw_data_shipment2$details, ~{sum(as.numeric(str_extract_all(string = ., pattern = '[0-99]+'))))` ).

Comment: Thank you for you help.